# Server Error in '/' Application - The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/insert.php' is not allowed

Tags: php, html, database

I am trying to use PHP to connect to a database from a website.

I am using the following php:

```
<?php
$con = mssql_connect("Server","user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_error());
  }

// some code
?>
```

And I am trying to send the results of a web form to the database, using:

```
 <form action="insert.php" method="POST">
```

However I am getting this error back:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/insert.php' is not allowed.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you using URL rewriting by any chance?

Comment: Which web server are you using? Any thing special like a proxy configured?

Comment: In regard to the URL rewriting, not to my knowledge, and I am just using local host, running the website from visual studio, I changed the command to 'GET' and it can download the php file fine, but I need to post.

Comment: It may just be an IIS setting in Windows 7 however im not sure.

Comment: I changed the php file extension to .aspx, when running this it does not bring back an error however doesn't actually bring back anything in the browser window, even after I removed the database credentials, I thought it would have brought back 'Could not connect: '

Comment: possible duplicate of [The HTTP verb POST used to access path '\[my path\]' is not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610433/the-http-verb-post-used-to-access-path-my-path-is-not-allowed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/insert.php' is not allowed.

Nothing to do with PHP.

Nothing to do with your database.

You're webserver is refusing to pass the (POST) request to PHP because it has been configured NOT to.

Comment: Exactly. I bet that even a zero-byte *.php file will trigger this error.

Comment: Ok so how do I reconfigure to to allow? I know there is a control in handler mappings however not sure.

Comment: Did you try google? Or the IIS manual? (hint: applicationhost.config)